# RoboHelp CSH always goes to the first help page

Tags: robohelp

I have a WebHelp content directory created using RoboHelp 9.  From a web application, I'm trying to display a specific help page using their CSH JavaScript API:

```
RH_ShowHelp(0, "WebHelp/index.htm>MainWindow", HH_HELP_CONTEXT, <some map id>);
```

The problem is, the resultant popup always displays the first help topic, regardless of the map id I pass.  Does the map file that was created for the RoboHelp project need to be included somewhere in the resultant WebHelp directory?  I would think that RoboHelp would handle including whatever it needed in the generated content.

I think what's more likely is that I messed up somewhere in generating the map file/ids.  To generate the map ids, I did the following:

- Created a new map file
- Double clicked it to open the map file window
- Selected everything from the right list block (all the topics and help sections)
- Clicked 'Auto Generate'

Are there further steps I need to follow before CSH will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you forgot to include your mapfile in the generated output. 
This is done in Web Help, under Content Categories.

Then, you can specify the topic number in the last argument to RH_ShowHelp.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the published output (not the generated output) in your content directory?

If that doesn't help, you can use simple links like this, which open the specified topic in help in the Help framework:

```
http://example.com/WebHelp/index.htm#someSubfolderThatIsAChildOfTheRootHelpFolder/theTopicYouWant.htm
```